# SetCursorPos Не учитывать DPI

Tags: c#

В общем проблема такая, приложение c# использует GetCursorPos и SetCursorPos. В виндовс установлено разрешение 1280x1024 и включен DPI scale 125%! Из за этого начинает не правильно работать данные функции. как сделать чтобы приложение c# игнорировало DPI scale ? чтобы я написал SetCursorPos(1280, 1024) и курсор установился в правый нижний угол экрана как это происходит без включенного DPI scale в системе.

Comment: DPI можно узнать, соотнести со стандартным и менять цифры на реальные. В случае с 125 - домножать цифры перед вызовом метода на 1.25.

Comment: А GetCursorPos из библиотеки user32.dll - даёт тот же глюк? (я много писал на winapi)

Comment: Вы случайно пишите не "мышь без границ" или не подобие "удалённый рабочий стол" или там radmin?

Comment: Нет, ничего такого специфического не пишу. Элементарное перемещение курсора, посредством user32.SetCursorPos. В итоге такая хрень получается. Помогает описанное ниже мною способ. но это такой себе вариант...

Answer (score 1):

Пока что нашел только один способ решения данной проблемы. В свойствах:

Файл -> Совместимость -> Отключить масштабирование изображения при высоком разрешение экрана.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить эту строку в самом начале функции Main():

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) SetProcessDPIAware();
```

Добавить сигнатуру функции SetProcessDPIAware():

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
```

Это поможет.